# Access object property that is outside of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, testing, protractor

My page object is structured so that I have all of the elements in an object and then an array of objects containing data about the fields that can be looped over to test max char length and error texts.

I would like the locator to reference a property that is outside the array so that the value does not need to be updated twice if the element changed.

Snippet from page object as an example...

```
module.exports = {
    siteName: element(by.id('P662_NAME')),
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'site name',
            max: 45,
            locator: element(by.id('P662_NAME'))
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried using the following with no luck...

```
this.siteName, this.siteName, module.exports.siteName
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to have the locator available outside the field objects themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :
Export from a file like this

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bas-fg1c2

```
var siteName = "dsdsd";
var fields = [
  {
    name: "site name",
    max: 45,
    locator: "dsdsd"
  }
];
module.exports = {
  siteName,
  fields
};;
```

Get it imported like this:

```
import { siteName } from "./test.js";
console.log(siteName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exporting looks pretty good. Import it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set `siteName` as another variable and reference that in your `fields` object like this:

```js
let siteName = "foo"; // now, updating this variable will also update the one in fields

let fields = [{
  // other props
  locator: siteName
}];

console.log(fields[0].locator); // expects "foo"

// module.exports = { siteName, fields };
```